# Javascript, enabling disabled fields on submit isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

```
$(function() {
    $("#booking-form").submit(function() {
        alert("hi");
        $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Initially, I have my `#Booking_clientPackagedService_id` disabled.

So I implemented the above code to re-enable it when the form is submitted.

But I found out that it is not enabling. The `alert("hi");` is working but not for the `.prop()`.

Is it because of the syntax itself? Or is there some other ways to do it?

Please advise thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code ?

Comment: looks like you are submitting a form, which might be resulting in the page being reloaded... so try to add a `return false` at the end of the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault();` to block the form to be *submited*.

If you want to submit 2nd time, than you can verify if a class exist and add it after fields have been enabled.

```
$(function() {
    $("#booking-form").submit(function(event) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('submited'))
        {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent form to submit
            alert("hi");
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").attr("disabled", false);
            $(this).toggleClass('submited');
        }
    });
})
```

Check the snippet to see the working example.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#booking-form").submit(function(event) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('submited'))
        {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent form to submit
            alert("hi");
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").attr("disabled", false);
            $(this).toggleClass('submited');
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="booking-form">
  <input type="text" id="Booking_clientPackagedService_id" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Okay so this enables the field BUT how do I proceed to submit right after enabling?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#Booking_clientPackagedService_id').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault();` the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
   $("#booking-form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").removeAttr('disabled');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$("#booking-form").on("submit",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", false);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("#booking-form").submit(function() {
        alert("hi");
        $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", false);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can makeuse of `localstorage` in your case:

```
var issubmitted = localstorage.getItem('issubmitted') !== undefined && localstorage.getItem('issubmitted') === 'submitted' || false;
$("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", issubmitted);

$("#booking-form").submit(function() {
    localstorage.setItem('issubmitted', 'submitted');
    alert("hi");
});
```